# How to explain a (bi)-LSTM model with SHAP? (code included)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, shap

When I try to run the example for [Keras LSTM for IMDB Sentiment Classification](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/text_examples/sentiment_analysis/Keras%20LSTM%20for%20IMDB%20Sentiment%20Classification.html)
shap_values invokes the following:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

The same problem is described [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1551).
I tried every listed suggestion [here](https://github.com/slundberg/shap/issues/1551), and so far none have worked.

I am using shap==0.41.0, tensorflow==2.12.0, keras==2.12.0, numpy==1.23.5.

I am trying to explain a bi-LSTM model with SHAP similarly to the example code above.
**My question: Please provide me with either:

1. rewrite of the above example code to explain a lstm-model (does not need to be deepexplainer. Does not even need to be strictly shap!
2. A combination of package versions, (preferably with installation instructions within a conda environment) where the above code works.**

Thanks in advance!